# New RAM doesn't work with old RAM

Tags: memory

I just bought RAM (Samsung ddr2 1gb 400MHz 2 sticks) and it doesn’t work when i put it in my pc. Without the new ram my pc works fine, when I only use the new RAM it also works fine but together it doesn’t work. I have got 4 RAM slots, in the first one I have placed my Hynix DDR2 1GB 667 MHz and in the second slot Kingston DDR2 2GB 800MHz

So the new ones:

Samsung PC2-3200R-333-12-C3 DDR2 1GB 400MHz 2 sticks. **[X][Y]**

The old ones:

- Hynix PC2-5300U-555-12 DDR2 1gb 667 MHz 1 stick **[Z]**
- Kingston KVR800D2N6 DDR2 2gb 800MHz 1 stick **[R]**

**Motherboard:**

- HP Compaq DC7100 SFF Small Form Factor Motherboard Sp# 361682-001 As# 356033-002

**RAM slots setup:**

- Slot1: R
- Slot2: Z
- Slot3: X
- Slot4: Y

(I switched my RAM around but it didn't do anything)

PC:

Hp compaq dc7700 sff

Any idea what i could do to make it work?

Comment: There are a lot of possible issues here. Can you please clarify your question with the exact layout of your RAM, i.e. `SLOT 0: x; SLOT 1: y; SLOT 2: z; SLOT 3: q` as well as your motherboard make/model?

Comment: Just some other avenues to look into: What are the voltages and CAS timings on all the chips?  Can you run the 2 new sticks with one of the old ones, just not with the other?  Have you tried rearranging which slots hold which RAM?  Is there a BIOS update available for your motherboard?

Comment: @techturtle my bios is uptodate and i tried all possible combination in the slots but none of them worked

Comment: @JaredT i updated it

Comment: For starters, you're using three different types of RAM in your computer. Assuming your motherboard is dual channel, you're using sticks `R` and `X` for one channel, then `Z` and `Y` on the other channel. Your sticks are different speeds, probably different timings, and even different memory capacity. How to make it work? Step 1. Buy four sticks that have matching or very closely matching specs.

Comment: @DrZoo but if the first to slots are 1 channel how can i put 2 diffrent sticks in it without problems?

Comment: That's the problem. Your sticks are probably too different in specs, which is what is causing your issues. Give us the exact models of your RAM sticks or the specs for each stick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HP's dc7700 Small Form Factor supports max 4 x 1 GB.

Single 2 GB modules not supported. While it may be possible for the system to run with a single 2 GB module. The chances of the system to work with different size modules is very less for this system.

Also, you are mixing three different speeds. 400 MHz, 667 MHz, 800 MHz.

Either try 2 GB 800 MHz + 1 GB 400 MHz, 1 GB 400 MHz, slot 4 empty Or,
Try 2 GB 800 MHz + 1 GB 667 MHz.

If both configurations fail. Remove 2 GB module and try with three 1 GB.

Anything above 4 GB for this system, is not guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, it appears that [the maximum RAM your system supports is 4GB](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c00229814), but you are attempting to install 5GB.  You could try adding just a single stick and see if it works, since that should only bring you to 4GB.

If maxing it at 4GB still won't work, then you have another incompatibility.  Your system only supports up to 400MHz, so the old ones should already be clocked down to that speed.  However, if you are mixing 1.35v and 1.5v RAM, one of them might not like being over or under clocked to match the new set and would cause it to fail to boot.

Comment: If i search for the voltage it says all of them are 1.8v and only adding one doesn't work **I MADE A TYPO LOOK AT MODEL AGAIN**

Comment: Oh yeah, DDR2 was higher voltage than DDR3.  Have you tried the 2 new sticks with just 1 of the old ones?

Comment: Just tried not working

Comment: You might try heading to www.crucial.com and run their analyzer to see what the suggested RAM specs are, as well as the maximum amount supported (that will be more accurate than me googling random model or part numbers).  Unfortunately, even if all the specs line up, sometimes there are just unaccountable differences in hardware than can make things incompatible.  You may have to just ditch the 2 new sticks or get 2 more just like them.

Comment: If i have to believe crucial it has to work but it doesn't. I mean i bought it on marktplaats (Dutch version of eBay) for €6 so ditching isn't that big of a deal but i just want it to work